# Detail in the proof that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {10}]$ is not a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra

We want to show that $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {10}]$, so we assume: $$2=(a+b\sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10}),\quad  a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z$$
While there exists an automorphism, call it $f$, sending $\sqrt {10} \mapsto -\sqrt {10}$, we can also write (**why can we?**): $$2=(a-b\sqrt{10})(c-d\sqrt{10})$$
and then we get: $$4=(a+b\sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10})*f(a+b\sqrt{10})*f(c+d\sqrt{10})=(a^2-10b^2)(c^2-10d^2)$$

Why are we allowed to multiply elements from the original ring with their images under the automorphism $f$ and further build our logic upon this assumption? As far as I see it: $$(a+b\sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10}) \neq (a-b\sqrt{10})(c-d\sqrt{10})$$ in the "original" ring.

Comment: $f(2)=2$ as $f$ is a ring automorphism, and so it fixes all of $\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$(a+b \sqrt{10})(c+d\sqrt{10}) = ac + 10bc + (ad+bc) \sqrt{10}.$$

If this equals $2$, then by irrationality of $\sqrt{10}$ we must have $ad + bc = 0$.

But 
$$(a-b \sqrt{10})(c-d\sqrt{10}) = ac + 10bc - (ad+bc) \sqrt{10},$$
so $ad+bc=0$ gives that these are equal.

Comment: agh...thank you, hdighfan! :)